# 401 return randomly on some API

Tags: asp.net, api, authentication, iis

Our application is hosted on IIS on server. The majority of the time it works fine, but at seemingly random times we are getting the error "401" When the error occurs we log the url that was used for the request as well as the error. As a result I can copy the exact url that generated the error and paste it into a browser (or Postman). for instance, and get a valid response.
[image]. I have no idea what might be causing this error.

Comment: You will have to find the corresponding log entries from IIS log files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code and see what are the substatus codes.

Comment: You can use the [failed request trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr) to see detailed information.